# Calling stored procedure with rowtype as argument

Tags: python, stored-procedures, informix

I'm using database connector `informixdb` for Python.

I defined a stored procedure in the database.

As an example:

```
CREATE ROW TYPE passenger(
    p_ref INTEGER, -- Reference for the passenger
    p_name VARCHAR(200) -- Name of the passenger
);
```

And then I created a stored procedure that expects an argument of this rowtype.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE modif_passenger(passenger pax)
    RETURNING VARCHAR(3) AS return_code;
...
RETURN pax.p_ref
```

My question is, how can I call this procedure from my Python code?

If it weren't for the rowtype (as it was before I changed it...), I can call it like:

```
import informixdb
_conn = informixdb.connect('%s@%s'%(database,host), user=user, password=password)
_cur = _conn.cursor()
_cur.callproc(modif_passenger,(111,'Pepe Grillo'))
ref = _cur.fetch()
```

Comment: The short answer is it is going to depend on how the `informixdb` module has implemented support for row types (if it has implemented it). You have to have a mechanism to persuade it to treat the values as a row type.  I'm not clear where `modif_passenger` comes from and what it holds; that isn't shown in the question.  You'll be able to do it by creating the statement using the text notation that you'd use with DB-Access, with the obvious major downside that you have to deal with quotes etc in the names ([Little Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327)!).  And you reprepare the statement each time.

Comment: Thank you for your response (and for the great comic! :D), I suspected that the answer will be that. As far as I could investigate, `informixdb` does not support treating values as row type. Doing as you said was one way, but it has other flaws (e.g. I would had to make all type mapping myself and Little Bobby Tables sanitation). So I finally decided to change back the stored procedures to expect all arguments explicitly and not row types.